# 3 Questions about Magento XML RPC API

Tags: vb.net, api, magento, xml-rpc

API:

1. Is it possible to filter sale orders by full customer name? I need to do this instead of against first/last name
2. Is it possible to get store name/ID pairs via the API?
3. Is it possible to filter orders by shipping_country?

Answer (score 0):

1) Looking over: http://svn.magentocommerce.com/source/branches/1.5/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Api/V2.php

```
public function items($filters = null)
{
    //TODO: add full name logic
```

However the logic does seem to be present:

```
        ->addExpressionFieldToSelect(
                'billing_name',
                "CONCAT({{billing_firstname}}, ' ', {{billing_lastname}})",
                array('billing_firstname'=>"$billingAliasName.firstname", 'billing_lastname'=>"$billingAliasName.lastname")
        )
        ->addExpressionFieldToSelect(
                'shipping_name',
                'CONCAT({{shipping_firstname}}, " ", {{shipping_lastname}})',
                array('shipping_firstname'=>"$shippingAliasName.firstname", 'shipping_lastname'=>"$shippingAliasName.lastname")
        );
```

2) From my understanding the short answer is no.  However there is a get/set currentStore for Categories and Products but I don't think it will give you the pairs you're looking for.

http://svn.magentocommerce.com/source/branches/1.2-trunk/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Api/Resource.php

3) You *SHOULD* be able to use `addFieldToFilter` but I think the country list may be an integer. Optional filters you might want to use - more available operations in method `_getConditionSql` in `Varien_Data_Collection_Db`.

http://www.yireo.com/tutorials/magento/magento-programming/631-connecting-to-magento-with-soap-part-3

Hope this helps!